# Only return rows if all items with the same ID has all the same value in another column

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out a way to identify all ID's that only contain all of the same value in another column.

In the example above Looking for all SubID's that are inactive it would only return rows for C2 (ID's 2, 5, & 6).

Sample Data :

[image]

Comment: Self join, or group by to find subid's.

Comment: Where did the sample table data go?

Answer (score 0):

use group by and sub-query

```
  select t.* from 
  (select subid,status from t t1     
   group by subid,status
   having count(*)>1
  ) as t1       
  inner join t on t.subid=t1.subid and t.status=t1.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.subid = t.subid and t1.status = 'Active');
```

**EDIT :** If you want to get the `subid`s which have same status then you can do :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.subid = t.subid and t1.status <> t.status);
```

Comment: Your First solution seems to have worked! I will do some data validation but thank you!